# unordered_map rehasing on erase()

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, erase-remove-idiom

I am not entirely clear on whether `unordered_map` is allowed to perform a rehash when doing an `erase()`

It is pretty clear that rehashing can happen during `insert()` thus invalidating all iterators and references:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert

But `erase()` seems to preserve all iterators and references except for the ones erased:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase

However, that last page and the Standard, indicate that `erase()` worst execution time is `O(size)`. What operation can take linear time to complete and not modify the container in a way it invalidates iterators?

This post suggests that iterators are invalidated during erasure:
http://kera.name/articles/2011/06/iterator-invalidation-rules-c0x/

I also read somewhere that a future proposal will allow rehashing on `erase()`. Is that true?

If indeed rehashing occurs, the old iterate and erase algorithm is wrong right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a very bad hash, or pathological data, all of the elements can end up in one bucket, making it an O(n) traversal to locate/remove the element.

It is perfectly legal to implement a `std::unordered_map` using a (singly-)linked-list for the elements: [we can see that its iterator type is only required to fulfil the ForwardIterator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map#Member_types). This makes a linear traversal necessary to remove an element within a bucket, even when passing the iterator.

This is the operation that may take O(n) time, not rehashing.

Comment: Correct. This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @self, why? This is perfectly valid answer for the question as asked.

Comment: @SergeyA OP's asking about rehashing.

Comment: @songyuanyao, this is the meat of the question: *What operation can take linear time to complete and not modify the container in a way it invalidates iterators?* This answer gives a perfect answer to it. Rehashing was an (incorrect) guess by OP.